# Is it necessary to close StringIO in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Do we need to close StringIO objects after usage in Ruby in order to free resources, like we do with the real IO objects?

```
obj = StringIO.new "some string"
#...
obj.close # <--- Do we need to close it?
```

**Refining my question**

Closing File object is necessary because it will close the file descriptor. The number of opened files is limited in the OS, and that's why it is necessary to close File. But, if I understand correctly, StringIO is an abstraction in memory. Do we need to close it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- `StringIO#close` does not free any resources or drop its reference to the accumulated string.  Therefore calling it has no effect upon resource usage.
- Only `StringIO#finalize`, called during garbage collection, frees the reference to the accumulated string so that it can be freed (provided the caller does not retain its own reference to it).
- `StringIO.open`, which briefly creates a StringIO instances, does not keep a reference to that instance after it returns; therefore that StringIO's reference to the accumulated string can be freed (provided the caller does not retain its own reference to it).
- In practical terms, there is seldom a need to worry about a memory leak when using StringIO.  Just don't hang on to references to StringIO once you're done with them and all will be well.

---

**Diving into the source**

The only resource used by a StringIO instance is the string it is accumulating.  You can see that in stringio.c (MRI 1.9.3); here we see the structure that holds a StringIO's state:

```
static struct StringIO *struct StringIO {
    VALUE string;
    long pos;
    long lineno;
    int flags;
    int count;
};
```

When a StringIO instance is finalized (that is, garbage collected), its reference to the string is dropped so that the string may be garbage collected *if there are no other references to it*.  Here's the finalize method, which is also called by `StringIO#open(&block)` in order to close the instance.

```
static VALUE
strio_finalize(VALUE self)
{
    struct StringIO *ptr = StringIO(self);
    ptr->string = Qnil;
    ptr->flags &= ~FMODE_READWRITE;
    return self;
}
```

The finalize method is called only when the object is garbage collected.  There is no other method of StringIO which frees the string reference.

`StringIO#close` just sets a flag.  It does not free the reference to the accumulated string or in any other way affect resource usage:

```
static VALUE
strio_close(VALUE self)
{   
    struct StringIO *ptr = StringIO(self);
    if (CLOSED(ptr)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eIOError, "closed stream");
    }
    ptr->flags &= ~FMODE_READWRITE;
    return Qnil;
}
```

And lastly, when you call `StringIO#string`, you get a reference to the exact same string that the StringIO instance has been accumulating:

```
static VALUE
strio_get_string(VALUE self)
{   
    return StringIO(self)->string;
}
```

---

**How to leak memory when using StringIO**

All of this means that there is only one way for a StringIO instance to cause a resource leak: You must not close the StringIO object, and you must keep it around longer than you keep the string you got when you called `StringIO#string`.  For example, imagine a class having a StringIO object as an instance variable:

```
class Leaker

  def initialize
    @sio = StringIO.new
    @sio.puts "Here's a large file:"
    @sio.puts
    @sio.write File.read('/path/to/a/very/big/file')
  end

  def result
    @sio.string
  end

end
```

Imagine that the user of this class gets the result, uses it briefly, and then discards it, and yet keeps a reference to the instance of Leaker.  You can see that the Leaker instance retains a reference to the result via the un-closed StringIO instance.  This could be a problem if the file is very large, or if there are many extant instance of Leaker.  This simple (and deliberately pathological) example can be fixed by simply not keeping the StringIO as an instance variable.  When you can (and you almost always can), it's better to simply throw away the StringIO object than to go through the bother of closing it explicitly:

```
class NotALeaker

  attr_reader :result

  def initialize
    sio = StringIO.new
    sio.puts "Here's a large file:"
    sio.puts
    sio.write File.read('/path/to/a/very/big/file')
    @result = sio.string
  end

end
```

Add to all of this that these leaks only matter when the strings are large or the StringIO instances numerous *and* the StringIO instance is long lived, and you can see that explicitly closing StringIO is seldom, if ever, needed.

Comment: Still, anything that forces the garbage collector to run is a bad thing. The garbage collector is a big performance problem in heavy load.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "When a StringIO instance is ... closed ... , the string reference is dropped" is false. `s = StringIO.new; s << "foobar"; s.close ; s.string` gives you `"foobar"`.

Comment: @Andrew, Hi, Good to see you.  What I meant was that when the StringIO instance is closed, _its_ reference to the string is dropped.  You can see this in the code for the finalizer (which is called both to close the instance and when it is GC'd).  Thanks for pointing this out--I'll see if I can make it clearer.

Comment: @Andrew, This just in: #close doesn't free up any references.  Only the implicit close done by StringIO.open does.  More editing...

Answer (score 4):

In response to the other answers here: calling `close` *won't* help you save memory.

```
require "stringio"
sio = StringIO.new
sio.print("A really long string")
sio.close
sio.string # => "A really long string"
```

"A really long string" will stay around as long as `sio` does, `close` or no `close`.

So why does StringIO have a `close` method? Duck typing. Providing `close`, and throwing an IOError if you try to read or write from it, ensures it acts like a real `File` object would. This is useful if you're using it as a mock object while unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

When you close a `File`, it is important as the system has a limited amount of descriptors (assuming your on a UNIX, I have no clue what Windows does). With `StringIO`, there is another resource at stake: Memory. If the `StringIO` object has a lot to store, there is going to be a lot of memory claimed from the heap. On the other hand, the garbage collector does always close `IO` objects that it claims, but that assumes that you have an elegant way to put your object out of scope. Also, on a heavily loaded system, physical RAM is much more valuable then file descriptors. On my Linux box, 178203 is the max file descriptors. I doubt that you could reach that.

Comment: The StringIO object still stores whatever you've written into it until it gets garbage collected. As far as I can tell, calling `close` or `close_write` won't change anything.

Comment: Hm. I guess that invalidates my point. Although, as in @WayneConrad's answer bellow, it still may be a good idea to call `finalize` on it. Still, sometimes it makes for cleaner code, especially if you use `StringIO.open` as you suggest bellow.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is no. I/O streams are automatically closed when claimed by the garbage collector. Same answer to File I/O as well.

Comment: "automatically closed when claimed by the garbage collector" is not something you want, because you can't predict when that will happen. This is why you use `File.open { |f| ... }` for files, and you should do the same with `StringIO`

Comment: Yeah, but in general (especially for real files), the answer is yes, not no.

Comment: Wait, wait. Can you tell me why I need to close StringIO as opposed to File? As far as I understand, closing File is needed most of all to free file descriptors, and not so for the memory. If it is correct, why do we need to close StringIO?

Comment: @Evgeny: `File.close` also frees the in-memory buffers, so it releases memory as well. In the case of `StringIO`, you're only releasing memory.

Comment: Closing a file (when you don't have anything to do with it) is also good for the health of the file, if a system crash occurs. That is why Ruby offers you "atomic" File methods which open the file, operate on it, and automatically closes it.

Answer (score -2):

No, but it is good for memory optimization

Comment: in any language you have to allocate memory references. by the end tag you enform to any language to u r done with that variable. and works with the  garbage collector the process is same in any language

Comment: StringIO still stores whatever you've written into it even after you've called `close_write` on it.